# Optimizing a Game Loop

Tags: android

I'm new to game programming, and I'm currently just conceptualizing the game's engine. I was thinking about a block-based 2d-with-z-axis world, like a 3d Conway's Game of Life, or maybe Dwarf Fortress.

This got me thinking: I need to iterate over every entity in the 3d grid, every game loop. Let's say, 100x100x100 3d cube, plus another 100 if I allow overlaps. That's 1,000,000 to 100,000,000 objects per game loop. Not everything is moving (and of course not everything is rendered), but I need to check everything for physics (which would mean the entity would check the entities above (9), below (9) and besides (8) itself).

How can I optimize my game loop enough to maintain a reasonably fast game loop?

I'm currently using Android's built-in sqlite db to store each block's individual properties like HP and the like, but the gameMap is stored in memory as an array[100][100][100][100][entityId:entityType].

Or am I just overthinking this?

Answer (score 2):

The tricks basically come down to not checking stuff when you don't have to. Assuming your physics involves blocks stacking on each other, this would be stuff like not checking a stack if it's been at rest for a while and then start re-checking it if it gets bumped. Depending on what's possible in-game, you may also be able to ignore blocks below the surface.

Still, it's probably reasonable to do a million checks per game loop. Also, for your type of game you may not need to check everything every frame; it probably wouldn't be noticeable if you either did part of them every frame, or ran the block physics in a slower thread, separate from the rendering and player physics.

Really though, optimization is something that's better to backfit at the end rather than design from the beginning. The best plan is to code your game physics in the most straightforward way you can, get your basic code working and debugged, and if it's not fast enough, start trying optimizations while watching framerate.